# How to scan a network over Internet ?

Tags: networking

I want to scan a network which is over Internet I have its Live IP how do I access the computers inside it ? how do I explore the network ? it have few networks inside it. I tried

```
nmap IPADDRESS
```

but it only tells about its ports.

Comment: Use AngryIP. Or there was a different tool from Mikrotik (IIRC), but I can't recall it's name anymore.

Comment: @Shiki angryip, like nmap cannot scan the internals of external networks.

Comment: Even if you could reconfigure your network this way you would lose all security and hackers would control your network within day or a week at most.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scan the internals of another network from the outside, due to how networking works, you can only see what services are allowed into and out of it, you could only tell what is actually inside the network if you were to snoop on its communications.

Comment: how can I snoop the communications of a network ? and inject the packets of my own choice so i can figure out what going on there ?

Answer (score 0):

The closet thing to want you want is this.

If you setup a secure VPN.  You could connect to the VPN and then scan the network over the VPN.  You would have to configure the VPN server to allow you access to all the parts of the network you want to see.

Comment: no I do not want to setup vpn